# Back button of the device explanation

Tags: android, button, back

The application that has created multiple screens,

when I'm surfing on the application button to return the phone does not work.

I wanted to turn the button back of the unit itself, with some conditions:

when you press the back button, he will return to the previous screen, just exit the program if we do not have more screen to come back.

And before returning to the previous screen or close the program it reset the variable x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly. But you can alter the behavior of the back button in your activity by overriding [onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)

> public void onBackPressed ()
>   Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry, could give a further explanation?

Comment: It's a circle. Round and round it goes.

Comment: if I have three screens, and the User is viewing the third.

How to do when you click the back button, go to screen 2 and if you click again go to screen 1

Comment: This is the default behavior and you need to do nothing in that case. How are you calling the three Activities (I assume each screen is an Activity)? If you call startActivity(2) from 1 and startActivity(3) from 2, then you will get the desired result.